# Sending Triggered Email from Java or Spring Batch application

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I am trying to find, If I can suggest my company to use Excattarget email system, which can send email to registered users from Spring Batch application.

Is Triggered Emails API can be used here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are . This will involve using making SOAP API calls for simple triggered emails, or REST calls if you want to fire applications like journey builder. To familiarise yourself with API's for Salesforce Marketing Cloud, visit: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm